# Phabricator API - Create a Project is not working

Tags: phabricator

```
curl -k -s -X POST "https://phabricator_URL.eu/api/project.edit" \
    -d api.token=api-myapitoken \
    -d members.add=TestMember \
    -d name=TestProject \
    -d objectIdentifier= | jq -r
```

ERROR receive:

```
{
  "result": null,
  "error_code": "ERR-CONDUIT-CALL",
  "error_info": "API Method \"project.edit\" does not define these parameters: 'members.add', 'name'."
}
```

Link Used:
https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/project.edit/

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `members.add` as part of a list of transactions, and the users to add must also be a list:

```
curl -k -s -X POST "https://phabricator_URL.eu/api/project.edit" \
    -d api.token=api-myapitoken \
    -d transactions[0][type]=name
    -d transactions[0][value]=TestProject \
    -d transactions[1][type]=members.add \
    -d transactions[1][value][0]=PHID-USER-5555 \
    -d objectIdentifier= | jq -r
```

If you submit the API call you want to make through the conduit doc page, it will display the curl call needed to perform those same actions.